# I get an error "Cannot construct instance of" message when doing POST for the /events URL upvotes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, rest

I am testing a REST API and using spring-boot-starter-data-rest in Maven.
There's an existing Organizer data in the MySQL db server which has an id of 1.
I'd like to link the existing organizer to the venue.

```
ID  NAME            CREATED
1   Thomas Burgers  2021-05-31 12:58:18
```

**REST URL in Postman**

```
http://localhost:8081/events-api-project/events
```

**In Postman, I send this POST request to the REST URL above**

```
{
    "name": "ABC",
    "description": "Test Description",
    "startTime": "2017-08-29T14:46:18Z",
    "endTime": "2017-08-29T16:46:18Z",
    "zoneId": "US/Central",
    "organizer": "/organizers/1",
    "venue": {
        "name": "ABC XYZ",
        "streetAddress": "12345",
        "streetAddress2": "Spice Wood Springs",
        "city": "Austin",
        "state": "Texas",
        "country": "United States",
        "postalCode": "78750"
    }
}
```

**This is what I get as a response in Postman**

```
    {
    "cause": {
        "cause": null,
        "message": "Cannot construct instance of `com.dev.eventmanagement.entities.Organizer` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('/organizers/1')\n at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 7, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.dev.eventmanagement.entities.Event[\"organizer\"])"
    },
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.dev.eventmanagement.entities.Organizer` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('/organizers/1'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.dev.eventmanagement.entities.Organizer` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('/organizers/1')\n at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 7, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.dev.eventmanagement.entities.Event[\"organizer\"])"
}
```

**Organizer entity class**

```
package com.dev.eventmanagement.entities;
 
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
 
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
 
@Entity
public class Organizer extends AbstractEntity {
    private String name;
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organizer")
    private Set<Event> events;
 
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 
    public Set<Event> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }
 
    public void setEvents(Set<Event> events) {
        this.events = events;
    }
 
    // important! override equals and hashcode
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
 
        return Objects.equals(id, ((Organizer) obj).id);
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
 
    public Long getResourceId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

**Event Entity Class**

```
package com.dev.eventmanagement.entities;
 
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
 
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
 
@Entity
public class Event extends AbstractEntity {
 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;
 
    private ZonedDateTime startTime;
 
    private ZonedDateTime endTime;
 
    private ZoneId zoneId;
 
    private boolean started;
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Organizer organizer;
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Participant> participants;
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Venue venue;
 
    public Venue getVenue() {
        return venue;
    }
 
    public void setVenue(Venue venue) {
        this.venue = venue;
    }
 
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
 
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
 
    public ZonedDateTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }
 
    public void setStartTime(ZonedDateTime startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }
 
    public ZonedDateTime getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }
 
    public void setEndTime(ZonedDateTime endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }
 
    public ZoneId getZoneId() {
        return zoneId;
    }
 
    public void setZoneId(ZoneId zoneId) {
        this.zoneId = zoneId;
    }
 
    public boolean isStarted() {
        return started;
    }
 
    public void setStarted(boolean started) {
        this.started = started;
    }
 
    public Organizer getOrganizer() {
        return organizer;
    }
 
    public void setOrganizer(Organizer organizer) {
        this.organizer = organizer;
    }
 
    public Set<Participant> getParticipants() {
        return participants;
    }
 
    public void setParticipants(Set<Participant> participants) {
        this.participants = participants;
    }
 
    // important! override equals and hashcode
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
 
        return Objects.equals(id, ((Event) obj).id);
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Organizer is nested object not String, it seems you have to pass it with its attributes like you did for "venue".

Answer (score 0):

Organizer is a class, not a String like in your JSON. If you want to use this class model, you will have to POST the following JSON:

```
{
    "name": "ABC",
    "description": "Test Description",
    "startTime": "2017-08-29T14:46:18Z",
    "endTime": "2017-08-29T16:46:18Z",
    "zoneId": "US/Central",
    "organizer": { "name": "/organizers/1" },
    "venue": {
        "name": "ABC XYZ",
        "streetAddress": "12345",
        "streetAddress2": "Spice Wood Springs",
        "city": "Austin",
        "state": "Texas",
        "country": "United States",
        "postalCode": "78750"
    }
}
```

I doubt that is what you really want, but that's at least the source of the exception if you read the error message carefully. If you want to accept the payload that you show here, you will have to use DTOs. Usually, people just use the ids, not URL paths for associations. But even then, you need to take special care to avoid creating a new organizer and instead refer to an existing one. So in summary, people usually use DTOs for this and map that to entities in some layer. I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Event.class)
@CreatableEntityView
public interface EventDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
    String getDescription();
    void setDescription(String description);
    ZonedDateTime getStartTime();
    void setStartTime(ZonedDateTime startTime);
    ZonedDateTime getEndTime();
    void setEndTime(ZonedDateTime endTime);
    ZoneId getZoneId();
    void setZoneId(ZoneId zoneId);
    OrganizerIdDto getOrganizer();
    void setOrganizer(OrganizerIdDto organizer);
    VenueDto getVenue();
    void setVenue(VenueDto venue);

    @EntityView(Organizer.class)
    interface OrganizerIdDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
    }

    @EntityView(Venue.class)
    @CreatableEntityView
    interface VenueDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
        void setName(String name);
        String getStreetAddress();
        void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress);
        String getStreetAddress2();
        void setStreetAddress2(String streetAddress2);
        String getCity();
        void setCity(String city);
        String getState();
        void setState(String state);
        String getCountry();
        void setCountry(String country);
        String getPostalCode();
        void setPostalCode(String postalCode);
    }
}
```

With the Spring [WebMvc integration](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#entity-view-deserialization) saving this is a matter of just passing the object to the repository:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/events", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> updateCat(@RequestBody EventDto event) {
    eventRepository.save(event);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(event.getId().toString());
}
```